# react-zxing toggle issue : camera doesn't turn OFF

Tags: reactjs, camera, ref

I am using [react-zxing](https://github.com/adamalfredsson/react-zxing) to scan the barcode on my webpage.
I have two options to scan the barcode,

1. Scan the barcode by using the zxing library and
2. Manual input the barcode.

#### Issue:

1. If I switch to "Manual Input mode" and then switch back to "Scan mode", the scan view gone.
2. If I switch to "Manual Input mode", camera doesn't turn OFF. (On my laptop, there is a camera indicator light which becomes ON if the camera is in use)

#### Live code

You can see live code : https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-jerry-1jr2xx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of `react-zxing`.

Try making your video element a custom component with the `useZxing` hook in it, so that zxing is properly reinitialized once the video element is rerendered.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I unmount the zxing component based on two buttons.

Comment: Looking at the codesandbox you've provided, it seems like the reference used by the ´useZxing()´ hook is unmounted. However, the hook expects a stable reference. The component using the hook should be unmounted along with its reference as well. Therefore, try using the hook inside with an inner component, which is unmounted when toggling input mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding paused in the options of `useZxing`.
The camera will stop when `manualInput` is `true`.

```js
const { ref } = useZxing({
  onResult(result) {
    setResult(result.getText());
  },
  paused: manualInput
});
```